# how do I make pyinstaller use python 2.7 when I also have 3.5?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

It seems to automatically use the latest version, and I haven't been able to find the answer in the pyinstaller documentation.
 It complains that my python2 code has incorrect syntax but it does not.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 178, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 413, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 144, in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 888, in run_script
    co_ast = compile(contents, pathname, 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST, True)
  File "/home/chuck/Pictures/testpics/photoresize.py", line 59
    print "incorrect options please choose from d(irectory),s(ize),e(xtension),r(ecursive) or use defaults"
                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: have you tried setting the path locally to python 2?

Comment: no I dont know how to do this but i like this idea better than reinstalling python2 in a virtual env to avoid python3 conflicts. I will google 'how to set the path locally to python2' and then I guess I just change it back when I'm done? I'm not sure how this would affect other programs or the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not willing to install a virtual environment as you commented, an easy workaround would be:

1. locate the path where python 2.x is installed ex: (not sure): `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`
2. open a console
3. type `PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7:$PATH`
4. type `python --version` just to check that it says V2 something not V3
5. run your pyinstaller executable with the `python` prefix

That doesn't affect system path (local to the console), so no need to revert back to previous path settings. Just close the console when you're done.

Also, don't use `sudo` as it's not needed and it changes/resets the path, which was your problem as you confirmed.

Comment: /usr/bin/python2.7                                                           
/usr/lib/python2.7                                                           
/usr/include/python2.7

Comment: check the directory you're targetting: it must exist (of course!) and must contain an executable file named `python`

Comment: doesn't seem to work :(

[chuck@PSYCH testpics]$ PATH=/usr/bin/python2.7:$PATH
[chuck@PSYCH testpics]$ sudo pyinstaller photoresize.py                      
[sudo] password for chuck:                                                   
47 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2                                                    
48 INFO: Python: 3.5.2                                                       
48 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.8.13-1-ARCH-x86_64-with-arch

Comment: what does `python --version` gives you? Oh, the `sudo` part may be a problem since it changes the path. Are you sure you need `sudo` prefix?

Comment: interesting, I did not know that sudo changes the path. you're right I don't need to use sudo and it worked fine without it. thank you.

Comment: I'm on arch linux so python --version gives 3.5 and python2 --version gives 2.7 fyi

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/#), or
[virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html)
With virtualenv it's possible to create separate environments with different versions of Python.
virtualenvwrapper is wrapper for virtualenv some how easier to work with.

Comment: I may need to do this but I really just want one program to run using python2.7 one time, so, seems like a lot of installing just for one time use

Comment: That is how I did installation:

Comment: **sudo apt-get install python-pip**, **sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv**. Man page for virtualenv [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/virtualenv.1.html). Take a note of -p and --system-site-packages.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned I'm using arch linux so I dont have apt-get I have pacman. I also would prefer to not dive into virtual environments for a one time use